# Use PasteSpecial twice in a row on the same sheet results in an error

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to copy values from one worksheet to another. Further I want to keep the format.
I use the following code

```
Set-Location C:\Users\...\Desktop

$xl = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$wb_new = $xl.Workbooks.Add()


$importFile = 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\someFile.xlsx'
$wb_loaded = $xl.Workbooks.Open($importFile)

$wb_loaded.Sheets.Item("Gross_MAT").Cells.Copy()
$wb_new.Sheets.Item(1).Cells.PasteSpecial(-4122)
$wb_new.Sheets.Item(1).Cells.PasteSpecial(-4163)

$wb_new.close($true)
$wb_loaded.close($false) 

$xl.quit()
```

but it returns an error:
"Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range class"

If I only paste once it does work. It also works when I select a different sheet (for example item(2)).

Comment: Have you verified that `$wb_new.Sheets.Item(1).Cells` returns the same type of information both before and after calling `PasteSpecial()` the first time? The paste into the empty cell probably expands the selection

Comment: I think you are right. Thats exactly the problem. But how can I fix that? I could use a fixed range but I want to stay dynamic as well @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Calculate the next cell after the last one in the range you get back from `Cells`?